# primeng sort icon issue

Tags: angular, primeng

need to primeng sort icon in same position even after it navigate to another page and come back on to same

just I checked in primeng table what are the property to retain the icon in same position but cant able to get solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sort icon direction retain even after navigate another page and come back to same page